# How to test window.load() in Jasmine with a specific window.location.href?

Tags: jquery, jasmine

I have the following code:

```
window.onload= function() {
     var requestData = {
        bookId:$('.bookId').text()
     };
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/viewbook")!=-1){
    $.post("check-book", requestData, function (response) {
       if(response == "already saved") {
           $('.add-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       }
    });
}
};
```

And I am trying to write an appropriate test in Jasmine. So, far I have the following code:

```
describe("should disable button", function () {
it("should check if book exists in list while loading page", function () {
    var localContext = {
        "window":{
            location:{
                href:"/viewbook"
            }

        }
    }
    with(localContext){
        spyOn($, 'post');

        window.load();
        expect(window.location.href).toBe("/viewbook");
        //expect($.post).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
});

});
```

But when I run it, it gives me an error that load is not know for an Object. Do you have any idea how this can be tested?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have replaced the `window` global (which I would think is kind of dangerous) with the copy defined in the variable `localContext`. That variable does not have a `load` method, so calling it gives you the above error.

A better solution to would be to create a named function and test its internals, and assign that function to `window.onload`, rather than trying to test an anonymous function assigned to the global `window`.

i.e.

```
function checkBook(){
    // Do stuff
}
window.onload = checkBook;
```

You can then manually run `checkBook` as often as you want in your tests.