# Tesing window.onload JS function using Jasmine framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am testing window.onload function using jasmine framework. My javascript code is as below -

```
window.onload = windowonloadFunction();

function windowonloadFunction(){
    if('WebSocket' in window){
    document.getElementById('supportmsg').innerHTML = 'Hi';
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/check.png";
    document.getElementById('supportmsg').appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

and my Spec code is as below -

```
describe('Test Suite for windowonloadFunction function',function(){

    it("This test check all tasks performed on window.load",function(){

        affix('label[id="supportmsg"]');
        windowonloadFunction();
});
});
```

when I run SpecRunner.html file, I am getting error - 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your original code is wrong; you're calling the function too early.

Comment: document.getElementById('supportmsg') does  not exist yet.

Comment: Calling which function is too early exactly? If it is wrong then what is the correct way of doing this? My Javascript function is working properly but test case is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of your windowOnLoadFunction(). Please follow the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/3/)

```js
var fun = {}
fun.windowonloadFunction = function() {

  document.getElementById('supportmsg').innerHTML = 'Hi';
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "http://www.hyundai.co.uk/test-import/model-profiles/small_cars/i10_premium_sweet_orange.png";
  document.getElementById('supportmsg').appendChild(img);

};



describe("A suite", function() {
  var element;
  beforeEach(function() {
    element = $("<div id= 'supportmsg'/>");
    $(document.body).append(element);
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    spyOn(fun, 'windowonloadFunction').and.callThrough();
    fun.windowonloadFunction();
    expect(fun.windowonloadFunction.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Observations:

- Is your aim to test the window.onload function itself or the
  functionality of the windowOnLoadFunction which you have defined? If
  the latter is the answer you are on a right track, however if the
  former is your answer, then I'm afraid you are trying to meddle with
  the global window itself which is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588882/how-to-test-window-load-in-jasmine-with-a-specific-window-location-href).
- You'll need to set up the HTML element before your test runs, that is
  the reason why you are running into the error that you mentioned.
  There are many ways to do it, like affixing the element, or using
  fixtures or simply setting up the elements in your beforeEach
  function.
- Also if you are trying to test a code, you can use [spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E) and
  callThrough() to call it and at the same time track the spy.